# How do you add items (not folders) to "My Favorites" in the Team Explorer window of Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: tfs, favorites, team-explorer

More specifically, I have query that pulls work items from multiple Team Projects. Since it is not specifically associated with any one Team Project, placing it in My Favorites makes more organizational sense than placing it in the My Queries folder.

Answer (score 1):

In team explorer, you can simply right click the query a choose add to favorites.
In the web access, you can also add a specific work items to your favorites (this is not available in VS team explorer)